# Determining a matrix M that represents $\phi$ relative to a basis B

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is for a specific example.

Let V be a vector space of functions q : **$R^2$** $\to$ **$R$** where f(x,y) = $a_1$$x^2$ + $a_2$$xy$ + $a_3$$y^2$ + $a_4$$x$ + $a_5$$y$ + $a_6$

$a_i$ $\in$ $R$ and $\phi$ : V $\to$ V be linear map given by

$\phi$(f) = $\partial$/$\partial$x $\int$ f(x,y) *dy*

**Question**: Determine the matrix M that represents $\phi$ relative to the basis $B$ = { $x^2$, $xy$, $y^2$, $x$, $y$, 1 }

Do you get $\phi$($x^2$) = 2$xy$, $\phi$($xy$) = $y^2$/2, $\phi$($y^2$) = 0, $\phi$($x$) = $y$, $\phi$($y$) = 0, $\phi$(1) = 0 then represent it as a matrix so the 1st column would be "0 2 0 0 0 0 ", 2nd "0 0 1/2 0 0 0", 3rd "0 0 0 0 0 0", 4th "0 0 0 0 1 0" and last two columns are all Os?

Or do you get $\phi$(f(x,y)) = 2$a_1$$xy$ + $a_2$$y^2$/2 + $a_4$y then use that?

I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. The next parts ask for the minimal polynomial and Jordan normal form so i assume the main diagonal in M has non-zero entries.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The general process for representing a linear map $\phi: V \to V$ as a matrix with respect to a basis $B$ is very simple:

1. Compute the images of the elements of $B$ under $\phi$.
2. Write each of those images as a sum of elements of $B$.
3. Use the coefficients of those terms as the entries of your matrix.

In this case, you have already done the first two steps, so you need only write down the matrix

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

> Or do you get $\phi(f(x,y)) = 2a_1xy + a_2y^2/2 + a_4y$ then use that?

You could also do it this way: you'd get the exact same answer.

> The next parts ask for the minimal polynomial and Jordan normal form so i assume the main diagonal in M has non-zero entries.

Neither of those requries the main diagonal to have non-zero entries.